# is it okay to use a custom Hook for every functionality? or should I keep the use of hooks in my project to a minimum?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

as of now, I am making a ReactJs web application that is a chatroom using Firebase
i have created a dedicated hook for each functionality for example, there are hooks like

- useSignup
- useLogin
- useLogout
- useAuth
- useCollection
- useSendMsg

that return a function that performs the tasks indicated by the name of those custom hooks, using hooks for these look attractive to be because it allows me to return state checkers like isLoading and isError along with their functions, those are simple useStates that i set during the process to manage the loading and error states.

there are other hooks I create that are related to context, i like to call contexts inside hooks because that way the code looks a lot more elegant and de-cluttered for example i created hooks like

- useAuthContext
- useCurrentRoomContext

I am not over-doing it am I? I was curious about were do I draw the line? is it healthy to use Hooks like this? should I change my Programming approach?

Comment: You're overthinking it. Hooks, like any other function, are meant to reduce duplicate code and make your code more declarative (when using it, it shows what you intend to do, with the actual implementation abstracted away). So it is perfectly reasonable to have hooks for all of these.

Comment: Custom hooks are nice and [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) pattern to abstract **reusable** parts of business logic away from your components to achieve more loosely coupled designs. So I would say, in general, it is a good practice.

Comment: Custom hooks are not slowing down your code or anything, they work just as if you had written the code directly inside each component where you use them. Contexts one can overuse, but the ones you have sound reasonable